# GridView.builder and Image.network perfomance issue

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to show a grid of 40 images from pisum.photos. I fill the list of URLs with an asynchronous function. The images are then displayed using gridview.

And it works, but I have serious performance issues (15-20 fps when scrolling). I googled so many times and found nothing. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MainList(),
    );
  }
}

class MainList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainListState createState() => _MainListState();
}

class _MainListState extends State<MainList> {
  List<String> images = <String>[];

  Future<void> fillList() async {
    // Fill the list with links
    var json = jsonDecode(
        (await http.get("https://picsum.photos/v2/list?limit=40")).body);
    setState(() {
      Map<String, dynamic> item;
      for (item in json) {
        images.add(item['download_url']);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Displaying Images"),
        ),
        body: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: images.length,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              child: Image.network(images[index], fit: BoxFit.cover),
            );
          },
        ));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fillList();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem is the `API` returning a list of very high-quality images with big sizes:

```
   {
      id: "1001",
      author: "Danielle MacInnes",
      width: 5616,
      height: 3744,
      url: "https://unsplash.com/photos/1DkWWN1dr-s",
      download_url: "https://picsum.photos/id/1001/5616/3744"
   },
   {
      id: "1002",
      author: "NASA",
      width: 4312,
      height: 2868,
      url: "https://unsplash.com/photos/6-jTZysYY_U",
      download_url: "https://picsum.photos/id/1002/4312/2868"
   },
```

The images are downloaded in original quality and they're only resized into the layout. This causes the performance issues and eventually crashes of the app.
The `API` doesn't allow specifying a width/height for the `list` endpoint, but we can achieve the same result by request random images, such in the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MainList(),
    );
  }
}

class MainList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainListState createState() => _MainListState();
}

class _MainListState extends State<MainList> {
  String _getRandomImage(int width, int height) {
    var rng = new Random();
    return 'https://picsum.photos/$width/$height?random=${rng.nextInt(999999)}';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Displaying Images"),
      ),
      body: GridView.builder(
        //itemCount: images.length,
        itemCount: 30,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            child: Image.network(
              //images[index],
              _getRandomImage(512, 512),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

The drawback is that instead of using only one `HTTP` request, this solution requires `(n)` requests, where `(n)` is the desired number of images.